# WCF REST service 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, wcf, wcf-rest

I have WCF RESTful service and Android client.

Server replies with 400 when I do bigger request. It seems that I have 65k limit issue like
in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324194/wcf-rest-service-template-4-0-bad-request) or in other million posts on same problem.

However, I can't seem to be able to fix it. Here is how my web.config looks

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="myEndpoint" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is code example of service function:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/trips/{TripId}/inspection", Method = "POST")]
        [Description("Used on mobile devices to submit inspections to server")]
        public void PostTripInspection(string tripId, Inspection inspection)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Here is code inside my Web project which hosts WCF (Global.asax.cs)

```
private static void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            // Setup URL's for each customer
            using (var cmc = new CoreModelContext())
            {
                foreach (var account in cmc.Accounts.Where(aa => aa.IsActive).ToList())
                {
                    RouteTable.Routes.Add(
                        new ServiceRoute(
                            account.AccountId + "/mobile", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MobileService)));
                }
            }
        }
```

From what I understand Java HttpClient doesn't impose any limits so it's on WCF side. Any pointers on how to solve this issue or how to intercept message in WCF?

EDIT 2:
This is what trace shows. And when I modigy standardEndpoint it doesn't help...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use streaming in this case - all you need to do is to  increase the maxReceivedMessageSize quota on the standard webHttpEndpoint:

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
    <standardEndpoint name=""
                      helpEnabled="true"
                      automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

**Update**: if the config change didn't work (I don't know why), you can try increasing it in code. By using a custom service host factory, you get a reference to the endpoint object and you can increase the quota there. The code below shows one such a factory (you'll need to update the `RegisterRoute` code to use this new factory):

```
public class MyWebServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }

    class MyWebServiceHost : WebServiceHost
    {
        public MyWebServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            base.OnOpening();
            foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in this.Description.Endpoints)
            {
                if (!endpoint.IsSystemEndpoint)
                {
                    Binding binding = endpoint.Binding;
                    if (binding is WebHttpBinding)
                    {
                        ((WebHttpBinding)binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CustomBinding custom = binding as CustomBinding;
                        if (custom == null)
                        {
                            custom = new CustomBinding(binding);
                        }

                        custom.Elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>().MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what is seems, right? Makes sense to me but doesn't work :( See updated main post. I ran trace and YES, this property seem to be the problem. I wonder what binding I need to modify..

Comment: It should work, but if it doesn't, you can try the update solution I added to the answer.

Comment: I will mark your post as Answer since you pointed me back to where I should look. Guess WHAT?! It started to work after I removed "name = "" " from endpoint. Microsoft service configuration editor complained about it but code wouldn't register this config with any name. Tag has to be out...

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if you've seen this link ([Similar StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177118/uploading-files-wcf-web-api-endpoint)):

> By default the WCF Transport is
>   limited to sending messages at 65K. If
>   you want to send larger you need to
>   enable **Streaming Transfer Mode** and
>   you need to increase the size of
>   **MaxReceivedMessageSize**, which is there
>   just as a guard to prevent someone
>   killing your server by uploading a
>   massive file.
>
> So, you can do this using binding
>   configuration or you can do it in
>   code. Here is one way to do it in
>   code:
>
> ```
> var endpoint = ((HttpEndpoint)host.Description.Endpoints[0]); //Assuming one endpoint
> endpoint.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
> endpoint.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;  // Allow files up to 10MB
> ```

Comment: For programmatic setting, see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/streaming-large-data-files-using-webhttpbinding-wcf.aspx.  Or, via web.config, try adding transferMode="Streamed" to the binding element.

Comment: This link doesn't show where endpoint get's configured. But anyway, I think this is not right direction. My Android client does plain POST, there is no streaming involved. It just POSTs big json string..

Comment: The binding for the endpoint is configured in the Test() method of that link.

Comment: I see. But it's showing how SERVER streams data back to client. Like I mentioned, in my case server does not reply to client with data. Client posts big json to server. So, I need to configure server so it listens and doesn't reject

Comment: @katit That code was only relevant to people using the new WCF Web API library from http://wcf.codeplex.com

Comment: It demonstrates both directions.  UploadFile involves the Client performing a large HTTP POST to the Server.  Follow the UploadFile logic in the example

Comment: I edited my original post to show you all the code I have. I think I should be able to do what I need via web.config but seems like nothing works.